# Reordering list according to another list in python

Tags: python

so the problem is I have a reference list that is the name of the columns. Then the user might have a different order of items in their list, so I would like to restructure their list according to my reference list. Lets take a look at an example:

We have the reference list.

```
ref = ['meats', 'veggies', 'beers', 'soda']
```

All lists should follow this, with meats first, then veggies, then beers, then soda. 
So a valid list could be

```
valid_1 = ['beef', 'carrot', 'pilsner', 'cola']
```

Now a user has a list of items in the wrong order, **but i know their order**. As an example

```
invalid_1 = ['cucumber', 'stout', 'lamb', 'pepsi']
```

Their order of items is given, so i know its `['veggies', 'beer', 'meat', 'soda']`.

So the question is, what is the fastest way of morphing their list into the order that i want according to the reference list?

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Where are you defining what is in the categories `['meats', 'veggies', 'beers', 'soda']`?

Comment: The placement in valid_1 list, so I know valid_1[0] is in 'meats' according to my reference

Comment: But where are you creating the association between `'cucumber'` and `'veggies'`? Are you asking about the NLP problem of determining if `'cucumber'` is related to `'veggies'`?

Comment: Nothing in the python specification or libraries can tell you that stout is a kind of beer. You'll need actual data for that.

Comment: What they are is irrelevant. This is only a matter of reordering the invalid list according to the reference list. 
I know how the user has ordered the invalid list with his ordering of labels

Comment: I'm guessing, from a mix of your comments and question, that you get two arguments as input: `invalid_1 = ['cucumber', 'stout', 'lamb', 'pepsi']` and `invalid_1_kind = ['veggies', 'beer', 'meat', 'soda']`, isn't it?

Comment: @olivecoder you are correct. I see now that my question is vague

Comment: You can zip those, then sort them by reference.index() although that's an O(n) lookup on each comparison. There's probably a better way. Can you just store a dict? Oh wait, do the lookup when you make the zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the question is according to my accepted comment you can do:

```
def arbitrary_sort( values, values_kind, ref_kind ):
   indexed_ref = { k: i for i, k in enumerate(ref_kind) }
   indexed_dic = { indexed_ref[k]: v for v, k in zip(values, values_kind) }
   return [ indexed_dic[i] for i in sorted( indexed_dic ) ]
```

The time complexity is O(NlogN) as the first two operations are linear and then we have a call to the `sorted` function.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i need.